# jQuery on change issue

Tags: jquery

Hello I have the following code (HTML + jQuery):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#btn_CSV, #btn_XLS").hide();
                $('#FileType').on('change', function() {
                    var selectedItem = $('#FileType option:selected').index();       
                    if(selectedItem === 1){
                        $('#btn_XLS').hide();
                        $('#btn_CSV').show();
                    }else if(selectedItem === 2){
                        $('#btn_XLS').show();
                        $('#btn_CSV').hide();
                    }
                });
                $("#selector").on('click', function() {
                    $('#FileType').val("CSV");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <button id="selector">Select CSV</button>
            <select id="FileType" >
                <option value="default" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">--Select option--</option>
                <option value="CSV">CSV</option>
                <option value="XLS">XLS</option>
            </select>
            <button id="btn_CSV">CSV</button>
            <button id="btn_XLS">XLS</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I select "CSV" from the dropdown a button labeled "CSV" will apear, the on('change') jQuery event works, but If I click on the select CSV button after the page is loaded the CSV option in the dropdown is selected but the CSV button does not apear. How can I make the on(change) event work for the dropdown on the "select CSV" button click too?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's quite simple — simply trigger the `change` event manually after you have set the value, i.e.:

```
$('#FileType').val("CSV").trigger("change");
```

The reason why the `change` event does not fire when you manipulate the value by `.val()` is because the event is only triggered by user interaction — not programatically. Therefore, the value change by JS is not recognized as a `change` event (in other words, the `change` event is not fired). This necessites using `.trigger()` to fire the event manually ;)

See working snippet below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn_CSV, #btn_XLS").hide();
  $('#FileType').on('change', function() {
    var selectedItem = $('#FileType option:selected').index();
    if (selectedItem === 1) {
      $('#btn_XLS').hide();
      $('#btn_CSV').show();
    } else if (selectedItem === 2) {
      $('#btn_XLS').show();
      $('#btn_CSV').hide();
    }
  });
  $("#selector").on('click', function() {
    $('#FileType').val("CSV").trigger("change");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button id="selector">Select CSV</button>
  <select id="FileType">
    <option value="default" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">--Select option--</option>
    <option value="CSV">CSV</option>
    <option value="XLS">XLS</option>
  </select>
  <button id="btn_CSV">CSV</button>
  <button id="btn_XLS">XLS</button>
</div>
```